# SQL query: Join two tables with where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem with a SQL query. I got the following query working, which pretty basic:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE Date = CURDATE()
```

There's a column in table1 which is called `h_id` and a `table2` with the columns `h_id` and `name`

I want to join those two tables so that I have the names out of table 2 from the current date.

I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work

```
SELECT t2.name, t1.field2
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.H_ID = t2.H_ID
WHERE t1.Date = CURDATE( )
```

Comment: SQL Server, Sybase ASE, Oracle?

Comment: What doesn't work - what result are you getting?

Comment: You mean, there is no result? I think your critiera Date = CURDATE() will not be true as curdate include timestamp.. Please check.

Comment: SQL Server, I'm getting a null result, but I should be getting one entry with name and field2

Comment: What do you mean by `null result`??

Comment: are you sure there exists a row in table2 that has a matching h_id for the entry in table1 that has today's date?  Try changing the INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN to check this

Comment: @Mexxer: Are you sure this is SQLServer? As has been pointed out in the answers, `CURDATE()` is specific to MySQL.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It might be case sensitive.

or

does table1 have field2 column?

If not/so, and according to your question, try it like this:

```
SELECT t2.name
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.h_id = t2.h_id
WHERE t1.Date = CURDATE()
```

---

Another possibility is the where clause, try it like this:

```
SELECT t2.name
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.h_id = t2.h_id
WHERE convert(varchar, t1.Date, 112) = convert(varchar, getdate(), 112)
```

---

A last possibility is that there isn't any h_id equal from table1 and table2.

Answer (score 2):

try to remove the `WHERE t1.Date = CURDATE( )` and see if your record is returned.
If it is, there is a problem with your `CURDATE( )`, try using getdate() or try to format the date

Comment: yup, when I remove the where clause I get all results. but getdate() doesn't work

Comment: or as at last resourse try day(t1.Date) = day(getdate()) and month(t1.date)=month(getdate()) and year(t1.date)=year(getdate())

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server does not support `curdate()`. That's for MySQL.

The appropriate function is `getdate()`

Here is a link to the official [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx)

**Edit:**

As you said in a comment, if `getdate()`doesn't work then you're using MySQL, then. Try this:

```
SELECT t2.name, t1.field2
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.H_ID = t2.H_ID
WHERE date(t1.Date) = date(CURDATE())
```

Comment: I wonder why -1... `'curdate' is not a recognized built-in function name.` [link](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/62835)

Comment: How can he get an empty result if the query is not parseable? Please, explain.

Comment: It means that the user has defined curdate(). There was probably a transition somewhere where he/his company switched from MySQL to SQL Server, and rather than rewriting everything they just defined curdate().

Comment: I find it extremely more likely that he didn't properly explain the issue he was having and that he confused `null result` with `error` than what you say. If it was that way he should have at least explain what `curdate()` was returning, right?

Comment: He answered another user's answer by saying that removing the where altogether returned results, but using getdate() didn't work. He's probably just using MySQL and not SQL Server like he thought.

Comment: @SamDeHaan If it were a user defined function, it would have to be prefixed with the schema.  There's nothing that I know of in SQL Server that would allow `curdate()` to be valid syntax.

Comment: Totally agree with you on that. Requirement issues... as always :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT t2.name, t1.field2
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.H_ID = t2.H_ID
WHERE t1.[Date] = GETDATE( )
```

or alternatively (MySQL):

```
SELECT t2.name, t1.field2
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.H_ID = t2.H_ID
WHERE t1.`Date` = CURDATE( )
```